# Spring boot context comes as null when implementing ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

I have created a Context class to store information about beans i want to create at runtime.

```java
@Component
public class Context {

    private final Map<String, Properties> annotatedMap;

    public Context() {
        this.annotatedMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void register(String entityName, Properties properties) {
        annotatedMap.put(entityName, properties);
    }

    public boolean isEntityPresent(String name) {
        return annotatedMap.containsKey(name);
    }
}
```

Below is the class that implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
class BeanRegistry implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar {

    @Autowired
    private Context context;

    private final ClassScanner classScanner = new ClassScanner();

    @Override
    public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {

        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = ((ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) registry);
        List<Class<?>> classes = classScanner.findAnnotatedClasses("*", MyCustomAnnotation.class);

        classes.forEach(c -> {
         
            String name = c.getSimpleName().toLowerCase();

            if (!this.context.isEntityPresent(name)) {

                // Rest of the logic
            }
            else {
               // Throw some error
            }

        });

    }
}
```

But when i run the application, I get the following error

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.app.Context.isEntityPresent(String)" because "this.context" is null`

I tried replacing `@Component` on BeanRegistry with `@Configuration` but the result is same.

Also I tried Autowiring ApplicationContext, but that also comes as null.

Comment: You cannot use autowiring in an `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` as that component acts very early in the lifecycle before the context has been fully initialized. The `BeanDefinitionRegistry` is basically the `ApplicationContext` that is being filled.

Comment: @M.Deinum is there any other way to store the properties in some context, that can later be shared between other classes.

Comment: you can implement ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> to collect bean details.  To update the Context object.

  `DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry registry = (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry) applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    registry.destroySingleton("context");
    registry.registerSingleton("context", ....);`

Comment: Properties can be put in the application.properties which you can access through the `Environment` or bind them to an properties object.